# iReport plugin doesn't find FBDriver class

Tags: java, jdbc, jasper-reports, firebird, ireport

I'm trying to connect my application to my Firebird database, and I need to generate a report in iReport plugin, I'm using JDK 1.8.

When I set the Firebird JDBC Driver (`org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver`)  in iReport it returns a ClassNotFound exception.

I already tried to import the `jaybird-full2.2.11.jar` to the classpath but no success.

Comment: Did you try to use Jaspersoft Studio?

Comment: Did you really use `org.firebirdsql.jdbcFBDriver`? Because that should be `org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver` (note the `.` before `FBDriver`), also the driver jar is `jaybird-full-2.2.11.jar`. It would be really helpful if you post the **full** stacktrace.